# Drop Postgresql user created by another user

Tags: database, postgresql

Consider I have two admin users in my postgres database admin1 and admin2. Now I login using admin1 and create a new user temp. I can delete this user using the login admin1 but when I try deleting it using admin2 it gives me the error 'role "temp" cannot be dropped because some objects depend on it'.

Create admin user statements are:

```
create user admin2 with password '...admin2';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO admin2 WITH grant option;
ALTER USER admin2 CREATEROLE;
```

Is there another permission that I need to give to admin2 so that i can delete temp?

Create temp user statements are:

```
create user temp with password '... temp';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO temp;
```

My drop temp user statements are:

```
REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public FROM temp;
REVOKE ALL ON DATABASE database FROM temp;
DROP USER temp;
```

Comment: server version, please

Answer (score 0):

`CREATEROLE` is enought to be able to delete roles. But all dependencies need to be removed. The error message is telling you there are still dependencies.

As per [manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-droprole.html) you can remove dependencies with either [`REASSIGN OWNED`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-reassign-owned.html) or [`DROP OWNED`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-drop-owned.html). For instance

```
REASSIGN OWNED BY temp TO admin2;
```

Comment: If thats the case, then why does it get deleted when I delete it using the user(admin1) who created the user without having to reassign owned by.

Comment: Good point, not sure are you certain the revoke's work correctly when executed as admin2?